# Windows 7 explorer hangs on key press

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Ok, so I have a really weird problem on Windows 7 64 bit: Whenever I press a key in an `explorer` window (a file window, wifi connection dialog, and others) the process hangs.

What could be up? I thought a reboot would fix it, but it didn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh, I forgot I made this question. Anyway, I solved it. I installed a tool called "System Control Manager" which doesn't really do much more than showing a fancy popup if you press Fn keys (volume up/down, brightness up/down, etc.).
Shutting it down (and permanently by deinstalling) fixed it.